# Logic Book Undergraduate

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, book-recommendation

I am currently an undergraduate mathematics major. I want to learn more about logic specifically about propositional logic and predicate logic. I’ve learned the basics from a discrete math course, but I want to learn more because I have questions that I believe can be answered with further study. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if *Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide* is exactly what could help you find what you are looking for. It gives various recommendations on entry-level maths reading on various areas of logic, and in particular -- at the beginning -- on proposition and predicate logic. You should find something at a level that works for you.

[You can freely download it here.](https://logicmatters.net/tyl)